# How to import this date format in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, formatting

I have time recorded as follows in a csv file:

```
2/12/2014  3:57:31 PM
14/02/2014 8:06:27 AM
18/02/2014 3:38:42 AM
18/02/2014 6:06:47 AM
18/02/2014 5:37:48 PM
19/02/2014 3:44:14 PM
```

How do i need to read this in R as a date. Currently it recognizes this as factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read help of `read.table`, specifically the argument `stringsAsFactors`.
You will have to read the data as `character` then convert it to `POSIXct` time class

```
dat <- read.csv(text='2/12/2014  3:57:31 PM
14/02/2014 8:06:27 AM
18/02/2014 3:38:42 AM
18/02/2014 6:06:47 AM
18/02/2014 5:37:48 PM
19/02/2014 3:44:14 PM', stringsAsFactor = FALSE, header=FALSE)



dat$V1 <- as.POSIXct(dat$V1, format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

dat
##                    V1
## 1 2014-12-02 15:57:31
## 2 2014-02-14 08:06:27
## 3 2014-02-18 03:38:42
## 4 2014-02-18 06:06:47
## 5 2014-02-18 17:37:48
## 6 2014-02-19 15:44:14
```

Alternatively, you can use `scan` function if you have only 1 column in your file

```
dat <- as.POSIXct(scan(file = textConnection("2/12/2014  3:57:31 PM\n14/02/2014 8:06:27 AM\n18/02/2014 3:38:42 AM\n18/02/2014 6:06:47 AM\n18/02/2014 5:37:48 PM\n19/02/2014 3:44:14 PM"), 
    what = character(), sep = "\n"), format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
## Read 6 items

dat
## [1] "2014-12-02 15:57:31 MYT" "2014-02-14 08:06:27 MYT" "2014-02-18 03:38:42 MYT" "2014-02-18 06:06:47 MYT"
## [5] "2014-02-18 17:37:48 MYT" "2014-02-19 15:44:14 MYT"
```

You can replace `textConnection('.....')` with file name

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on whether each line is one factor, or if each line is three factors, so you may need to play around with the solution I am proposing below. Hint: it is best to give us the output of `dput()`, so we know *exactly* what you are working with.

```
foo <- scan(, what="",sep="#")
2/12/2014  3:57:31 PM
14/02/2014 8:06:27 AM
18/02/2014 3:38:42 AM
18/02/2014 6:06:47 AM
18/02/2014 5:37:48 PM
19/02/2014 3:44:14 PM

foo
as.Date(sapply(strsplit(foo," "),"[",1),format="%d/%m/%Y")
```